# Why didn't Han just go and get more co-axium?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, there's a train heist sequence at the start

> where the team succeed in stealing a car, only to fight over it with the marauders before it's lost (blowing up half a mountain in the meantime).

So, they end up losing what they stole and spend the rest of the film making up for their loss.

> But, the whole front end of the train (and cargo) went over the blown up bridge into the valley below, remarkably not blowing up half the planet.

Why didn't the crew retrieve their loot from this obvious location?

Comment: 1) We don't know if the front end of the train also contained coaxium 2) if it did, we don't see if it actually blows up or not 3) the train was guarded with stormtroopers and viper droids, so after an incident like that surely the people in charge of this transport are on maximum security and retrieved the front of the transport.

Comment: @Fatalize All good points. Why not post as an answer?

Comment: @Xantec They're merely suppositions, not canon points. I'm not willing to post an answer which is speculative.

Comment: @Fatalize What we've seen in the movie is enough to give a well informed answer from those multiple facets you addressed, and it's better than anything out so far. If something more definitive comes along later, someone can always give their own answer on that. I was going to answer along the same lines as you, but I'd defer to you and upvote yours if you wanted to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Mwr247 I agree.  We see plenty of non-canon answers here for this and other franchises.

Comment: @Fatalize Absent more authoritative sources, speculation backed by canon is acceptable.

Comment: They did seem happy to find the exact wagon with the coaxium. It was clear, at least for me, that it was the only one. Think about it, the rest of the train would have exploded like the wagon did.

Comment: @Xantec - Or we could just look in the (canon) junior novel

Comment: @Valorum That would be a more authoritative source. :)

Comment: @Xantec - Well, indeed.

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive, coming from a canon source of information. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Yes, a reminder...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Because the other cars on the train didn't contain coaxium.

> ***Beckett quickly found the train car that contained the coaxium**, and
> the three set to work attaching cables from the AT- hauler to the
> cargo.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Solo: A Star Wars Story: Train Heist](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story:_Train_Heist)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 15):

All the information provided in the film seems to clearly indicate there is no other coaxium on the train:

1st - we know from Beckett and later Dryden that finding this much coaxium at once away from a heavily guarded base is exceedingly rare.  The amount that Beckett was trying to steal would have been an unprecedented heist.  Assuming there was 12 times that amount lying around (each car loaded) seems very unlikely.

2nd - Given their plan the easiest car to steal would have been the last one on the train as it would only have to be decoupled on one side.  Instead, Beckett went to a specific car further ahead in the train and cut it open to make sure he had the right one.

3rd - Neither Beckett's gang or the "Marauders" that show up show any interest in any other car.  Everyone is after the same one.

And lastly is the detail you already mentioned.  The train didn't explode as it plunged into the ravine.

Comment: True. The other cars might have contained an assortment of food portions, blasters, spare droid parts, and other supplies. A crate of E-11 blaster rifles wouldn't be worth *as much* as the coaxium, true, but it would have been worth more than what they actually *got* from the heist, which was nothing. It implies that the other cars might have actually been *empty*, or that they simply did not have enough time to search the other cars.